Common check for two functions which prevents calling functions from executing further
Let's say we have two functions which first do some parameter checking. They return early if the checks are not met. Then they do stuff. Quite simple:
function funcA (inputParam) {
  if(!inputParam.valueA) {
     // Do error handling
     return;
  }
  // Do stuff
}

function funcB (inputParam) {
  if(!inputParam.valueB) {
     // Do error handling
     return;
  }
  // Do stuff
}

Now, after implementing and using those functions frequently, we realize that there is another condition which needs to be met in both functions. Of course, we do not want to copy&paste that parameter check, but re-use it for both functions. It is not that simple to put it into a function and call the function because the called function would need to make sure that the rest of the caller function is not executed if the param check fails.
A function like
function checkC (inputParam) {
  if(!inputParam.valueC) {
     // Do error handling
     return;
  }
}

will not work, because if we call it like
function funcA (inputParam) {
  checkC(inputParam)
  // Do stuff
}

then it will always reach Do stuff no matter the outcome of the parameter check, but if you do
function funcA (inputParam) {
      return checkC(inputParam)
      // Do stuff
    }

then Do stuff will never be reached of course.
So, what would be the most elegant way which requires the least refactoring?
Ideas I came up with:

Build a common function which would to be called first like

function commonFunction(inputParam, proceedWithAOrB) {
  if(!inputParam.valueC) {
    // Do error handling
    return;
  }
  if(proceedWithAOrB === 'a') {
    return funcA (inputParam);
  }
  if(proceedWithAOrB === 'b') {
    return funcB (inputParam);
  }
}

But that would require a significant amount of refactoring.

Split up the common function into one which checks the param and one which does the error handling like

    function checkParamC (inputParam) {
      if(!inputParam.valueC) {
         return false;
      }
      return true
    }
    
    function checkParamCErrorHandling (inputParam) {
      // Do error handling
    }
    
    function funcA (inputParam) {
      if(!checkParamC (inputParam)) {
         return checkParamCErrorHandling (inputParam);
      }
      // Do stuff
    }

That way, we would not need to copy&paste actual logic, but it is still not very elegant.
I feel like that I'm missing something and there must be a more elegant solution to this?
Edit For some reason, throw new Error... is not an option in my case.

how about if (!checkC(inputParam)) return; in the main functions?

You could just create a function with a callback that then only execute when this new condition is met.  Both functions can then use it, and then if later even more conditions are added, just update this function.

@Pointy That misses the // Do error handling part. Sorry, in real life, this is of course way more complex, Leaving aside much stuff.

Well if you're "leaving aside much stuff", it's not likely you'll get any suggestions that are truly useful to you.

Please explain why throwing errors is not an option?

@Salketer That's more of a code styling thingy. In my team, we usually use throwing errors for cases where think that we ended up in a bad state because our systems did something wrong, whereas the case I'm asking for is a more a problem of wrong user input, i.e. human error on the user's side. One can argue if that's a good decision, but that's not the scope of the question in any case :)

That's not the scope of the question, but the scope of the question is how to propagate errors to the callstack. In which case the real answer is throwing and handling an error.

@Salketer I somewhat disagree here. It's not only about errors. It's about how a called function can prevent the calling function from executing further. I've encountered such a situation also in different settings, where it was not about throwing errors. Stupid example: You need to check at two places if  something was already done and not proceed if so. In that case, do not want to throw an error. You want show a success message like "You have done that already elsewhere! Great!"

where think that we ended up in a bad state  bit OT, but that's actually a good way to code.   One of the biggest mistakes I see with JS is over using exceptions.  But saying that, if you descend and create a custom error ErrorUser or something like that, the cascading features of exception can be useful.   This new craze of errors as values I find bonkers!!..

@cis you can display a success message even if something got thrown... As a matter of fact, you can throw any value in javascript. Not that I suggest doing so, but you could catch and act accordingly if the error is of type Success... The way I see it, it still is an error as code can/should not execute because prerequisites are not met. It is to the developer to handle the error accordingly afterwards.

Also, in your "stupid example", you wouldn't be able to display the success message, as you would end up with just undefined as the function's feedback returns nothing. You could only know that something was wrong but not provide better information to user.

The scenario the OP describes asks for a solution based on what is known as decorators. In JavaScript one way of implementing this pattern was to provide them as function- respectively method-modifiers, implemented as methods itself at the Function.prototype.
The OP's specific use case can be solved best with an universal around modifier. One just has to integrate the slightly changed implementation of the newly provided "C"-check (hence the OP's checkC function) into a specific around-handler function where the latter gets passed as the first parameter to the before mentioned around method of e.g. funcA and funcB in order to create modified versions of each function with both now featuring the additional behavior that has been provided with the passed around-handler.
... example code ...


// - code which should not anymore be touched.

function funcA(inputParam) {
  if (!inputParam.valueA) {
    console.log('`funcA`/`valueA` specific error handling.');
    return;
  }
  console.log('`funcA` ... do stuff ...');
}
function funcB(inputParam) {
  if (!inputParam.valueB) {
    console.log('`funcB`/`valueB` specific error handling.');
    return;
  }
  console.log('`funcB` ... do stuff ...');
}

// - a much later additonally spcified check
//   which has to be run with the invocation
//   of either of the above functions.
function doesPassAdditionalCheckC (inputParam) {
  let isValid = true;

  if (!inputParam.valueC) {
    console.log('`additionalCheckC`/`valueC` specific error handling.');

    isValid = false;
  }
  return isValid;
}

// - implement an `around`-modifier and
//   "C"-check specific handler-function.
function proceedOnlyInCaseCheckCDoesPass(proceed, handler, ...args) {
  const inputParam = args[0];

  if (doesPassAdditionalCheckC(inputParam)) {
  
    proceed(inputParam);
  }
}
const valueA = 'foo';
const valueB = 'bar';
const valueC = 'baz';

console.log('\n+++ BEFORE MODIFICATION ... `A`/`B`-checks +++\n');

console.log('\nfuncA({}) ...'), funcA({});
console.log('\nfuncB({}) ...'), funcB({});

console.log('\nfuncA({ valueA }) ...'), funcA({ valueA });
console.log('\nfuncB({ valueB }) ...'), funcB({ valueB });

// - create and reassign the modified
//   version of a function, each from
//   and to its original reference.
funcA = funcA.around(proceedOnlyInCaseCheckCDoesPass);
funcB = funcB.around(proceedOnlyInCaseCheckCDoesPass);

console.log('\n+++ AFTER MODIFICATION ... `C` check-first +++\n');

console.log('\nfuncA({}) ...'), funcA({});
console.log('\nfuncB({}) ...'), funcB({});

console.log('\nfuncA({ valueC }) ...'), funcA({ valueC });
console.log('\nfuncB({ valueC }) ...'), funcB({ valueC });

console.log('\nfuncA({ valueC, valueA }) ...'), funcA({ valueC, valueA });
console.log('\nfuncB({ valueC, valueB }) ...'), funcB({ valueC, valueB });

console.log({
  funcA,
  'funcA.origin': funcA.origin,
  'funcA.handler': funcA.handler,
});
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
(() => {

  function isFunction(value) {
    return (
      typeof value === 'function' &&
      typeof value.call === 'function' &&
      typeof value.apply === 'function'
    );
  }

  function asConfiguredModification(modifierName, origin, handler, modified) {
    const nameDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(origin, 'name');

    Object.defineProperty(modified, 'name', {
      ...nameDescriptor,
      value: `modified::${ modifierName } ${ nameDescriptor.value }`,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(modified, 'origin', { get: () => origin });
    Object.defineProperty(modified, 'handler', { get: () => handler });

    return modified;
  }

  function asConfiguredModifier(name, modifier) {
    Object.defineProperty(modifier, 'name', {

      ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(modifier, 'name'),
      value: name,
    });
    return modifier;
  }
  const modifierConfig = { writable: true, configurable: true };

  // - implementing the behavior of
  //   an `around` modifier method.

  function aroundModifier(handler, target) {
    'use strict';

    const proceed = this;
    target = target ?? null;

    return (

      isFunction(proceed) &&
      isFunction(handler) &&

      asConfiguredModification(

        'around', proceed, handler,

        function /* aroundType */(...args) {
          return handler.call((this ?? target), proceed, handler, ...args);
        },
      )
    ) || proceed;
  }

  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'around', {
    ...modifierConfig, value: asConfiguredModifier('aroundModifier', aroundModifier),
  });

})();
</script>



Additional note
Method modifiers can be implemented in a way that they handle synchronous as well as asynchronous functions/methods for following scenarios around, before, after(Returning), afterThrowing, and  afterFinally with the latter two being capable of wrapping each a special try...catch handling around a function/method.
Thus with a combination of afterThrowing/afterFinally and around the OP can apply, to code bases that for "reasons" can not be touched anymore, a clean solution in terms of how to wrap for instance repetitive tests (e.g. guards) around other base functionality or even how to handle throwing code for functions which never have been provided with try...catch based error handling in the first place.

You could use a mixin...
function requireCheckC(callable){
    return function(inputParam){
        if(!inputParam.valueC) {
            // Do error handling
            return;
        }
        return callable(inputParam);
    }
}

const funcA = requireCheckC(function(inputParam) {
    if(!inputParam.valueA) {
       // Do error handling
       return;
    }
    // Do stuff
});

Basically the requireCheckC will return a function that first checkC and then follow with the execution of the function passed in parameter.
While I'd still say the best way would be to use error throwing for... well, handling errors...

I think that's similar to what @Keith mentioned in the comments. That would work I guess. But as soon as funcA would actually return an actual value to its caller function, it cannot work that way anymore, right?

I am not sure I understand what you mean? The funcA's behaviour will stay unchanged.

I meant just: Replace // Do Stuff in funcA by return 'foo'. Then call it funcA({valueC: true}). The result will be undefined and not foo. I hadn't mentioned that in the question as requirement and it is not a requirement, but it could become one later on. That's why I'm hesitant regarding a callback-refactor. But that has nothing to do with answer as such. Sorry for the side-track

Oh, sorry, you are right. Absolutely. Forgot what I said. I had missed something. My bad.

Since the mixin returns the value of the funcA, it should be exactly the same behaviour as before.
